# TFVC License for TFS Licensing

Tags: tfs, tfvc

we are using JIRA for requirement management and TFS for version control. Due to licensing issues, I only want to buy TFVC not the whole TFS including ALM.

Is there any option to buy only TFVC? Tried searching out, still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Source Code only option. The lowest license you can get that still allowes you to access source code is a TFS CAL. The features and access are outlined here https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/connect/change-access-levels. If your developers already have Visual Studio with an MSDN subscription, their licesning is already covered. Never take licesning advice about licensing without talking a MS salesperson though, but the Visual Studio Licensing Whitepaper does cover most of the ins and outs https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/tfs-pricing/.

If you're not using anything but source control, TFS would probably be a poor choice for your group.

Comment: And consider the **Visual Studio Team Services for TFS CALs** option which is the cheapest in some scenarios.

Comment: So what do you suggest in this scenario? We are dependent on JIRA and Confluence as all the requirement management is done over there. For version control, we must have to have this on premises. We are using Microsoft technologies that's why using TFS from a long time. Which version control you would recommend other than TFS?

Comment: If you're already on Atlassian, you could use https://www.atlassian.com/software/bitbucket or something like gitlab.com which is free.